# Is there any way of deploying the WP8 app "without Cable"

Tags: c#, deployment, windows-phone-8

I am a wp8 developer and searching for a way to deploy my app on device "**without the cable**". I have searched over the web and could find nothing helpful. **I know about he "Application Deployment" tool in WP8 SDK and my phone is also Developer Unlocked**. I know how to simply deploy an app on windows phone. All i am looking for is to know, Is there any way I can deploy my application to my phone **without using the phone cable**?

Lets say i dont have my cable with me, what options do I have now?

Comment: Yeah, there should be WiFi debugging :)

Answer (score 4):

Currently you can't debug an app on your phone without the USB cable. You can do this when developing for Windows 8.x so perhaps with the coming WP8.1 update we'll get the same feature for the phone..

There is the [beta testing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj215598%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) you could do for a test deployment through the store but the app will run through the cert. process so this is no option for testing while developing and there is no debugging.

Comment: yeah, you are pretty much right, I have debugged the Win8 apps using "Remote Machine" and I am hoping to find the similar solution for My WP8 app. I will post the answer here as soon I find one.

Comment: +1 for Beta tesing (there is also an option to see crash counts ;). Thought, it is not suitable for developing.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use the cable to deploy to your device. If you dont have a cable with you, just use the emulator.